# Identify a short story featuring a comedian on a space colony

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

The story was about a comedian named Dylan on a space colony (might have been a Dyson sphere) named Skinner. The populace of the Sphere had been implanted with some sort of conditioning to ensure a minimum of disruptive behavior. Eventually Dylan showed on TV the nature of this conditioning by telling a tragic story using sentences he had used as punchlines in his routines. Apparently you could also fly in the low gravity of the colony. I know it seems like I remember a good deal of the story, but apparently it's not searchable information. If anybody could help me with this, I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 8):

Sounds like it might be "Walden Three" by Michael Swanwick. It was first published in [*New Dimensions 12*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?23717) and reprinted in [*Best Science Fiction of the Year #11*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?4159). The [Google Books page](http://books.google.com/books?ei=_wq6Tsb4Oc69tgfW67CgBw&ct=result&id=mdvyybq-llEC&dq=%22dylan%22%20%22skinner%22%20space%20%28colony%20OR%20station%20OR%20sphere%29&q=%22dylan%22%20%22skinner%22%20%28comic%20OR%20comedian%29#search_anchor) for the latter has <sup>tiny tiny</sup> snippets matching the names (and a very incomplete table of contents). [Here's a review](http://theporporbooksblog.blogspot.com/2010/10/book-review-new-dimensions-12-edited-by.html) that matches the plot:

> The anthology leads off with Michael Swanwick’s ‘Walden Three’, about
> an L5 colony where all 10,000 inhabitants are required to be outfitted
> with an implant that guarantees happy behavior. A clown / standup
> comic / mime tries to rebel.

ISFDB has [bibliographic information](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?58069). And you might recognize the cover or other stories from the first two links.